# How to add a confirmation form upon submission of user profile form

Tags: forms

I have previously added a confirmation dialog to my own forms using a technique like http://blog.purdy.info/2014/04/how-to-work-with-confirmform-in-drupal-7.html.  However this assumes that you have control of the form builder and submit functions.  I now want to add a confirmation to the user profile form which is of course defined in the user module.

Any suggestions ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own submit handler in front the of the predefined submit handler using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

The [#submit property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) is an array of submit handlers and it allows multiple values. Use [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to put your handler in front of the predefined handler.

Your code will look something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id = 'target_form') { // make sure it's the right form
    // add my handler
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'my_submit');
  }
}

function my_submit( $form, &$form_state ) {
}
```

When the form is submitted, it will run `my_submit()` before the predefined submit handler.

Comment: The strategy for delivering the confirmation form requires modifying both the submit handler ( as you have suggested ) AND the function defining the form itself so that it returns a different form if a flag is set.  So unfortunately your answer is not a complete solution.